# Как вытащить функцию из DLL

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, dll

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

public static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

apiImport.SetWindowLongPtr(window, GWL_EXSTYLE, new IntPtr((long)WinSlylesEx.WS_EX_LEFT | (long)WinSlylesEx.WS_EX_LTRREADING));
```

Константы скопировал из `winuser.h`. Ошибка "Не удается найти точку входа "SetWindowLongPtr" в DLL "user32.dll"." Пробовал `SetWindowLongPtrA` и `SetWindowLongPtrW`.

Comment: Хмм... Открыл User32.dll (от Win7x32), там нет этой функции. Присутствуют только SetWindowLongA и SetWindowLongW. Хотя МСДН говорит, что они там должны быть... Может дело в этом кроется? Попробуйте явно указать какую функцию требуется вытащить из ДЛЛ посредством атрибутов импорта.

Comment: @pincher1519: не нужно, об этом позаботилась директива [`CharSet = CharSet.Auto`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b93s42f.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В [данном треде](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343724/how-do-i-pinvoke-to-getwindowlongptr-and-setwindowlongptr-on-32-bit-platforms) говорят, что маршаллить необходимо следующим образом:

```
// This static method is required because legacy OSes do not support
// SetWindowLongPtr 
public static IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong)
{
      if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
          return new IntPtr(SetWindowLong32(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong.ToInt32()));
      else
          return SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);          
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="SetWindowLong")]
private static extern int SetWindowLong32(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="SetWindowLongPtr")]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);
```

Comment: Возможно, стоит заменить условие на [`Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx)?

Comment: @AlexeyM 

- Да, я тоже подумал об этом, но этот класс есть только на `.NET >= 4.0`. Возможно, есть смысл использовать подход, описанный в http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net 

- Также есть информация, что этот способ маршаллить `SetWindowLongPtr` используется внутри `Windows.Forms`, а, значит, вероятно, может считаться надежным для соответствующих кейсов. См. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343724/how-do-i-pinvoke-to-getwindowlongptr-and-setwindowlongptr-on-32-bit-platforms

Comment: >В данном треде говорят, что маршаллить необходимо следующим образом

Собственно, в `WinUser` оно так и транслируется:

 #ifdef _WIN64
 ...
 WINUSERAPI
 LONG_PTR
 WINAPI
 SetWindowLongPtrA(
     __in HWND hWnd,
     __in int nIndex,
     __in LONG_PTR dwNewLong);
 WINUSERAPI
 LONG_PTR
 WINAPI
 SetWindowLongPtrW(
     __in HWND hWnd,
     __in int nIndex,
     __in LONG_PTR dwNewLong);
 ...
 #else  /* _WIN64 */
 ...
 #define SetWindowLongPtrA   SetWindowLongA
 #define SetWindowLongPtrW   SetWindowLongW
 ...
 #endif /* _WIN64 */